# Написать .bat-файл, запускающий несколько консолей

Tags: cmd, windows-10, bat

Нужно написать .bat файл, при выполнении которого будет открыто несколько отдельных cmd в которых выполнится своя команда (port-forward).

При старте файла должны выполниться несколько команд, типа:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/service-name 11111:22
```

Важно, что каждая такая команда должна запуститься из папки C:\Users%username% и выполниться каждая в своей cmd

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\%username%

start cmd.exe /k "kubectl port-forward svc/service-name1 11111:22"
start cmd.exe /k "kubectl port-forward svc/service-name2 11112:22"
start cmd.exe /k "kubectl port-forward svc/service-name3 11113:22"

exit
```

Comment: не очень получилось. Консоли открылись, но во всех одна и та же ошибка: 

E0411 17:53:07.327521    1096 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.24.40.61:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.24.40.61:6443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Ошибка, которую вы получили, не связана с самим .bat файлом, а скорее связана с проблемой при подключении к Kubernetes API серверу.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Проблема была в том, что я не запустил VPN, который необходим для этих подключений. Теперь всё работает, спасибо!